# IPython notebook connection failed issue

Tags: python-3.x

This is probably very simple; and I am embarrassed to ask; but I spent a long time trying to solve it already. I am trying to use an IPython notebook and on the click to get a Python 3 notebook, I often (but not always) get:

> Connection failed
>
> A connection to the notebook server could not be established. The notebook will continue trying to connect, but until it does, you will NOT be able to run code. Check your network connection or notebook server connection."

The obvious answer might appear that I have no internet connection; but I can access the internet and interact with external websites. It seems to be a problem of connecting with something local to my computer.

The really frustrating part is that sometimes in the past this has worked with no problem. That suggests to me that it is a simple setting issue. Does anyone have suggestions about how I can debug this?

My operating system is Windows (both 7, and 8.1). I am also using Anaconda 2.3 and Python 3.4

Comment: Try to check the browser console (Developer tools). are you maybe using Chrome? for some debugging ideas see http://andrewbolster.info/2014/07/ipython-websocket-failure-on-chrome/ (unfortunately it didn't solve my problem)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I eventually worked out my issue. If I make Chrome or Firefox my default browser then everything works. Our company has some mods to IE that kept it from working for that. The think to remember (for me) is that I have to set IE as my default for some company software, but must change it back to Chrome or Firefox for Jupyter. Then, it works like a charm!

Comment: In case it helps anyone else, my experience was the same as  @DaveSnell . My company was setting a proxy server for LAN connections that was messing up my connection to the JupyterHub server. In my case I was able to unset that proxy server setting, but you might also be able to get around this by changing your default browser as Dave did.

Answer (score 7):

Downgrade *Tornado* to 5.1.1 from 6.0, that will solve it.
Apparently, *Tornado* 6.0 breaks notebook.

Answer (score 0):

I anwser a similar question. And I agree with tchakravarty.

Maybe resulting from your proxy？I have been troubled for one afternoon for that，because I use nginx proxy_pass fo my jupyter to proxy to that port. But it always didn't connect, i look through the docs of jupyter notebook and found that [Jupter Proxy Issue](http://jupyter-notebook.readthedocs.io/en/latest/public_server.html#proxies)

 
And i change to use nginx rewrite rather than proxy, it works. So in my case, it can be caused by proxy.

Answer (score 0):

I was also facing the same problem and as the few people suggested to update the tornado version , I did but it din't help.

**What helped me was ---**

**I ran this two following commands -**

**python2 -m pip install --upgrade ipykernel**

**python2 -m ipykernel install**

In Jupyter Notebooks, the kernel is responsible for executing Python code. When you install the Anaconda System for Python3, this version also becomes the default for the notebooks. In order to enable Python 2.7 in your notebooks, you need to install a new kernel.